# Android custom sms notification tone for some contacts by code

Tags: android, notifications, sms, message

I want to change sms notify tone when i receive sms from few numbers or if sms message contain a couple of words is it possible?

I want to change tone for example when i get sms from my bank, and message contain a few of words like ('incoming','money','etc')

Comment: Since KitKat (API 4.4), this won't really be possible unless your app is the default SMS app. Before that, it would be possible to intercept the incoming SMS, issue your own notification with whatever ringtone you like, provided the user doesn't have another active app installed that has a higher priority for SMS receipt than yours; like Hangouts, for instance.

Comment: so if I use textra i can't do this because textra will stop my sound and play main system sound?

Comment: It depends on which Android version you're talking about, and at what priority Textra sets itself. I've not used Textra, so I don't know off-hand. However, if you're talking about KitKat or above, then no, you can't stop the default SMS app from playing its own ringtone. Though, you could still play your own custom ringtone afterward.